# Android instantiating and overriding pattern

Tags: java, android, lambda

I do not think this kind of OOP pattern exist in C#.net and C++. So what is the name of this pattern or feature. I encountered this when programming Android, is this a feature of Java too or not? Note : I know @Override is specific for android compiler/ide only.

```
Foo bar = new Foo(){
    @Override
    public void fighters(){
          //some stuff
    }
};
```

Is this somekind of Lambda thing?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean the "@Override"?  I'm sure that's in C# too.  You're just telling the compiler that fighters() overrides a superclass's method.

Comment: Look up "anonymous class" or "anonymous inner class"

Comment: It's just an inner class in Java.

Comment: And @Override is not just in "Android compiler/ide".

Comment: @StephaneMathis : Actually `@Override` is primarily only used to detect errors within the code and is not actually necessary for Java syntax. Any method in an extended class which has the same signature as a method in the super-class will, in fact, override the super-class method with or without `@Override`.

Comment: @Squonk, Oh, ok... I always saw it (not only in Android but for J2EE website and other things) so I assumed it was mandatory... At least in C# the override keyword is mandatory, I think.

Comment: @StephaneMathis : Actually `override` in C# is an access modifier and yes, it is required in certain situations (overriding virtual or abstract methods) but it's also possible to 'hide' methods in C# which is subtly different and allows defining methods with the same signature as in the super-class but defining them with the `new` keyword.

Comment: And it's got nothing to do with Lambda's

Comment: @laalto You answered my question perfectly precisely. Thank you! I am only beginning with Java/Android and I think these kind of Java features are breaking the design pattern I am used to. I am a C++/C# programmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is example of [inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) in Java. This is an anonymous inner class, where

*An anonymous class is an inner class that does not have a name at all. And whose instance is being created at the time of its creation.*

---

Read the [Anonymous Classes documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) for more detail. And Override is Java annotation (not specific to Android). Read [When do you use Java's @Override annotation and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why)

---

Consider the example below

Let, you declare an interface `HelloWorld` like below.

```
interface HelloWorld {
    public void greet();
    public void greetSomeone(String someone);
}
```

And you want to write a class which extends `HelloWorld`

```
class TestClass implements HelloWorld {
    String name = "world";

    @Override
    public void greet() {
        greetSomeone("world");
    }

    @Override
    public void greetSomeone(String someone) {
        name = someone;
        System.out.println("Hello " + name);
    }
}
```

and instantiate it as

```
TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
```

Here instead-of above two steps (declaring a class and instantiate it), you can just declare an anonymous inner class, like

```
HelloWorld testClass = new HelloWorld() {

    String name = "world";
    @Override
    public void greet() {
        greetSomeone("world");
    }
    @Override
    public void greetSomeone(String someone) {
        name = someone;
        System.out.println("Hello " + name);
    }
};
```

here `testClass` is an object of an anonymous inner class which implements `HelloWorld`.